# Realm same thread for NotificationToken observe commitWrite(withoutNotifying: [token])

Tags: swift, multithreading, realm

**The question is how to make objects observe and commitWrite in same thread.**

1. I want to observe objects changing in a Thread. It's easy to implement according to this article [Realm Notifications on Background Threads with Swift](https://academy.realm.io/posts/realm-notifications-on-background-threads-with-swift/).
2. However, there is a problem. I don't want to notify in some cases. 
   So I use `realm.commitWrite(withoutNotifying: [token])` to commitWrite.

Below code is **commitWrite without notifying**.

> **I want to run this code in the same thread with `BackgroundWorker`**

```
let realm = try! Realm()
realm.beginWrite()
realm.add(object, update: true)
try! realm.commitWrite(withoutNotifying: [notificationToken])
```

> Here is Realm's objects observe. It will run in the sub-thread (BackgroundWorker come from above link)

```
var worker: BackgroundWorker?
private func registerLocalDatabaseStep1() {
    worker = BackgroundWorker()
    worker?.start { [weak self] in
        guard let `self` = self else { return }
        `self`.registerLocalDatabase()
    }
}
private func registerLocalDatabase() {
    let objects = Cream<T>().realm.objects(T.self)
    notificationToken = objects.observe({ [weak self](changes) in
        guard let `self` = self else { return }

        switch changes {
        case .initial(_):
            break
        case .update(let collection, _, let insertions, let modifications):
            //do something
        case .error(_):
            break
        }
    })
}
```

> I posted the `BackgroundWorker` from above link to make it easier to read.

```
class BackgroundWorker: NSObject {
  private var thread: Thread!
  private var block: (()->Void)!

  internal func runBlock() { block() }

  internal func start(_ block: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.block = block

    let threadName = String(describing: self)
      .components(separatedBy: .punctuationCharacters)[1]

    thread = Thread { [weak self] in
      while (self != nil && !self!.thread.isCancelled) {
        RunLoop.current.run(
          mode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode, 
          before: Date.distantPast)
      }
      Thread.exit()
    }
    thread.name = "\(threadName)-\(UUID().uuidString)"
    thread.start()

    perform(#selector(runBlock),
      on: thread,
      with: nil,
      waitUntilDone: false,
      modes: [RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode.rawValue])
  }

  public func stop() {
    thread.cancel()
  }
}
```

According to [Realm API](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm11commitWriteFzT16withoutNotifyingGSaCSo20RLMNotificationToken__T_):

[image]

Again: **The question is how to make objects observe and commitWrite in same thread.**

I want to run `realm.commitWrite(withoutNotifying` in the same thread with `registerLocalDatabase()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, it's easy to run a code in the same thread.

update the class of `BackgroundWorker`

```
class BackgroundWorker: NSObject {
    private var thread: Thread!
    private var block: (()->Void)!

    @objc internal func runBlock() { block() }

    ///create a thread
    private func createThread() {
        let threadName = String(describing: self)
            .components(separatedBy: .punctuationCharacters)[1]

        thread = Thread { [weak self] in
            while (self != nil && !self!.thread.isCancelled) {
                // Poll to see if thread was canceled. If using
                // multiple threads `.distantPast` will cause 100% CPU
                // usage. If using `.distantFuture` the thread will never exit.
                RunLoop.current.run(
                    mode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode,
                    before: .now + 30)
            }
            Thread.exit()
        }
        thread.name = "\(threadName)-\(UUID().uuidString)"
        thread.start()
    }

    internal func start(_ block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.block = block

        //if thread is nil, create a new one. Otherwise run block in the same thread!!!!
        if thread == nil {
            createThread()
        }

        perform(#selector(runBlock),
                on: thread,
                with: nil,
                waitUntilDone: false,
                modes: [RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode.rawValue])
    }

    public func stop() {
        thread.cancel()
    }
}
```

> so, there is how to execute, use the same `worker` of `BackgroundWorker`:

```
`self`.worker?.start {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.beginWrite()
    realm.add(object, update: true)
    realm.commitWrite(withoutNotifying: [`self`.notificationToken])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can move Commit `commitWrite` to main thread like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.beginWrite()
    realm.add(object, update: true)
    try! realm.commitWrite(withoutNotifying: [notificationToken])
}
```

Comment: Hi Mika. It can not run in Main thread if this `notificationToken` is not created in Main thread. It will has an error: `'RLMException', reason: 'Incorrect Realm: only notifications for the Realm being modified can be skipped.'`

Comment: Ah, sorry my bad. I misread the question. So your token is created in background thread and writing happens in main thread. Can token be created in main thread and then just execute the heavy part of observer (that "do something") in another thread?

Comment: Hi Mika, I want to make them both in background thread. According to [the doc](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm11commitWriteFzT16withoutNotifyingGSaCSo20RLMNotificationToken__T_). They need to run in the same thread. So I want to run `commitWrite(withoutNotifying` method in the thread which created the Token.

Comment: Can `commitWrite(withoutNotifying` run in the `BackgroundWorker `'s thread

Comment: I can see that you solved it, great :) There were some limitations on passing Realm objects between threads that may become relevant later. See Realm docs: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#threading